Intercepting unhandled exception in UI thread without preventing the default unhandled exception dialog from being displayed in WinFormrs app
By default, when an unhandled exception is thrown in the UI thread of the WinFroms app, the default error dialog is displayed (ThreadExceptionDialog with a stacktrace and Continue/Quit buttons).
I can also subscribe to the Application.ThreadException event and provide some custom handling of the unhandled exceptions. But in this case there is no default error dialog shown.
I can show the default dialog explicitly doing something like this:
    Application.ThreadException += ApplicationOnThreadException;
    
    ...

    private static void ApplicationOnThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        using var dialog = new ThreadExceptionDialog(e.Exception);
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

But the docs claim that ThreadExceptionDialog is an internal API to support the product infrastructure "and is not intended to be used directly from your code". So the explicit call is definitely against the docs and therefore does not look reliable enoght.
Is there standard way to intercept the exception without preventing/overriding the default behavior with the default error dialog?

According to the source its an either or. You have your own handler or you get the standard dialog.
